# Chebyschev's Polynomials and its Application

Tags: approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

Consider approximating the function $f(x)=x^{3}-x$ by a polynomial $P_{2}(x)=a_{2} x^{2}+$ $a_{1} x+a_{0}$ which minimizes
$$
E_{2}\left(a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}\left[f(x)-P_{2}(x)\right]^{2} d x
$$
Find a polynomial $P_{1}$ that solves
$$
\min _{P_{1} \in \Pi_{1}} \max _{x \in[0,1]}\left|P_{2}(x)-P_{1}(x)\right|
$$
where $\Pi_{1}$ denotes a set of all polynomials degree at most $1 .$

It seems that such similar problems are mostly related to Chebyschev's polynomials, but I could relate precisely how these exercises could potentially yield to the inequalities involved with Chebyschev's ones? What are the major instincts or ideas behind those problems?

Comment: Are there any further ideas on such best approximations or Chebyschev's polynomials and their related properties?

Comment: The first one is quite simple. What did you try ?

Comment: The integrability is quite simple. What was interesting is how the polynomial $P_1$ could be achieved using Chebyschev's polynomials and some inequalities?